# MySQL unknown column in where clause (UNION)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, union

I have the following query:

```
select a.clei, a.partNumber, 
(
  SELECT count(*) FROM 
    ( SELECT * from search_upload_data s where a.clei is not null AND a.clei = s.clei 
      UNION
      SELECT * from search_upload_data s where a.partNumber is not null AND a.partNumber = s.partNumber 
    ) as t1
) as total
from api_analytics_data a
```

It is throwing the error:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'a.clei' in 'where clause'
```

I guess MySQL won't allow a join reference in the inner SQL, but I'm not sure how to get around this.

I need the count from search_upload_data, See SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/172ac/2

<=========================================================================>

**ADDITIONAL NOTE**

I need to figure out how to do this with a UNION. The OR conditions in everyone's answers work on a small scale, but bog down on the actual DB with a lot of data.

Here is the explain (for Rajat's answer):

[image]

Comment: I don't follow your query or your data.  Can you edit your question and describe, in detail, the logic behind what you are trying to do?  It is obvious why your current query is throwing an error, but at the moment I can't suggest anything to you.

Comment: Follow the link the the SQL Fiddle. It explains it in detail. -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/172ac/2

Comment: Also provide some sample data and expected result, maybe someone can come up with better solution.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/172ac/2

Comment: No, that Fiddle actually doesn't help here.  It has all your data, which is better than nothing, but it doesn't really explain the logic.  Your union query is complicated, we need to know what it is supposed to be doing.

Comment: The comment in the Fiddle explains it. search_analytics_data is the base data for a report. search_upload_data is a list of searches done. I need all records from api_analytics_data with the count of matches (searches) from search_upload data. Should be a sum of the UNION on all matching partNumbers (where IS NOT NULL) + all matching cleis (where IS NOT NULL).

Comment: See Fiddle comment for what the result should be.

Comment: `(5SC4FFD     Y6884A-V01AA    7)` <-- can you explain this first record from the result set?  I don't understand how you get 7 as a count.

Comment: Sure, no problem. So if you look at search_upload_data, for CLEI '5SC4FFD', there are 5 matching rows. For partNumber 'Y6884A-V01AA', there are 3 matching rows. However, 1 of those matching rows is also in the CLEI set. So there are 5 unique for CLEI + 2 unique for partNumber = 7. Check out the UNION statement in this Fiddle to make it clear --- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/172ac/46

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TRY THIS**: Simple join with `OR` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT a.clei, 
    a.partNumber, 
    COUNT(1) tot
FROM api_analytics_data a
LEFT JOIN search_upload_data s ON (a.clei = s.clei OR a.partNumber = s.partNumber)
    AND (a.clei is not null OR a.partNumber is not null)
GROUP BY a.clei, a.partNumber
```

**OUTPUT:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94e556/1

Comment: Works on small scale like example, but not with large amounts of data. See EXPLAIN added to my original question.

Comment: Please do `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` and check the performance.

Comment: Better at about 12 seconds, but still very slow.

Comment: I added an index, and it's quite fast now.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select a.clei, a.partNumber, 
 ( SELECT COUNT(1) As Total
       from search_upload_data s
       where ( a.clei is not null  AND a.clei = s.clei )
       OR (a.partNumber is not null AND a.partNumber = s.PartNumber)

    ) as t1 

from api_analytics_data a
```

Comment: This one works too. Going to do some benchmarks to find the fastest solution. Thanks.

Comment: For performance, i would say go with @Susang's query that would be faster.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these are usable. They work on a small scale, but on the actual database with millions of rows to match, the OR condition is causing a full table scan and it runs forever.

Comment: Could you please share the time taken by each query. I hope you have created indexes on Clie and part number as well.

Answer (score 1):

This corresponds with your desired output anyway. Just using a regular OR to select either *clei or partnumber*.

```
select a.clei, a.partNumber, 
(
  SELECT count(*) FROM search_upload_data s WHERE 
     (a.clei is not null AND a.clei = s.clei) OR 
     (a.partNumber is not null AND a.partNumber = s.partNumber) 
) as Total
from api_analytics_data a
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select a.clei, a.partNumber, 
(
  SELECT count(s.id) FROM search_upload_data s where (a.clei is not null AND a.clei = s.clei) OR (a.partNumber is not null AND a.partNumber = s.partNumber) 
) as Total
from api_analytics_data a
```

try now

Comment: I have modified

Comment: @scott80109 can you check again?